# Add class on click in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

My vue template:

```
<div 
  class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 thumb" 
  v-for="(photo, index) in photos" 
  @click.prevent="check(index)"
>
  <a class="thumbnail" :class="{'active': photo.checked}">
    <img class="img-responsive" :src="photo.picture" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

My check() method:

```
check(index) {
  if(!("checked" in this.photos[index]))
    this.photos[index].checked = true
  else
    this.photos[index].checked = !this.photos[index].checked
},
```

Everything seems correct but it's not working. What could the problem be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Vue cannot detect changes to an index of an array.](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/)

Get a reference to the `photo` object of the `index` passed to `check()` and then use [`Vue.set()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) to update the array like so:

```
check(index) {
  let photo = this.photos[index];
  
  if (!("checked" in photo)) {
    photo.checked = true
  } else {
    photo.checked = !photo.checked
  }
  
  Vue.set(this.photos, index, photo);
},
```

[Here's a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/jb5fhscw/)

Answer (score 3):

How about just `@click.prevent="$set(photo, 'checked', !photo.checked)"` and forget the handler?

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 thumb" v-for="(photo, index) in photos" 
    @click.prevent="$set(photo, 'checked', !photo.checked)">
  <a class="thumbnail" :class="{'active': photo.checked}">
    <img class="img-responsive" :src="photo.picture" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

If you want to use the handler:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 thumb" v-for="(photo, index) in photos" 
     @click.prevent="check(photo)">
```

And

```
check(photo) {
  this.$set(photo, 'checked', !photo.checked)
},
```

Comment: That was my first thought too. I'm not sure why, but this doesn't work if the `photo` doesn't initially have a `checked` property (which seems to be the case in the example). https://jsfiddle.net/jb5fhscw/1/

Comment: @thanksd if it doesn't have the property initially then it needs to be set via $set.

Comment: ah yeah that makes sense

Comment: Should we open an issue

Comment: @ChadidiAbdellah no that's expected behavior.

Comment: @ChadidiAbdellah  Updated for $set. I hate passing indexes around.